# How to change the default font in VMware Clarity?

Tags: angular, sass, vmware-clarity

This is from [documentation](https://clarity.design/documentation/typography):

> Clarity includes several SASS variables, collections, mixing, and
>   functions for working with typography. These are described below:
>
> $clr-font
>
> This SASS variable points to our default text font,
>   Metropolis.

I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the scss variables are customizable but you need to overwrite them with your preferred values. This can be done with a custom theme. The docs have details on how to set this up for an app built with the cli tooling: https://clarity.design/documentation/themes